# Using the power rule twice in one equation

Tags: calculus

Here is the power rule

[image]

In the following example the power rule is used two times and I do not understand why? Are they using the chain rule where "u" is used? If so what are they using for "u" and why is the power rule applied twice?

[image]

As mentioned as a suggestion in the comments here is my work:

$$y=((3x^{4}+1)^{7}+1)^{5}$$
$$dy/dx=5((3x^{4}+1)^{7}+1)^{4}*dy/dx((3x^{4}+1)^{7}+1)$$
$$=5(3x^{4}+1)^{4}*7(3x^{4}+1)^{6}+1$$

Comment: Chain rule twice as well.

Comment: Do you know why the chain rule is used twice? Is there a rule for this?

Comment: Have you tried to do this problem on your own to see what rules would be needed?

Comment: You need it as many times as it takes to unpack the determinant.

Comment: @Jack I just did the chain rule once for the answer but that is wrong. Is there a reason why the chain rule is used twice?

Comment: @Jinzu: if you could show your work in the post, then one (and maybe yourself) can help to figure out what's wrong in your calculation and how the chain rule should be used.

Comment: Hmm, are you really sure about your calculation of $dy/dx((3x^{4}+1)^{7}+1)$? `:)` Think carefully about how you should calculate this and then you will be able to answer your own question.

Comment: "Do you know why the chain rule is used twice? Is there a rule for this?" ... um... because that's how many times it took to get an answer?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the application of the chain rule where $y=u^5$ with $u=(3x^4+1)^7+1$.  Then they need $\frac {du}{dx}$ which can be seen as $u=v^7+1$ with $v=3x^4+1$.  Finally they need $\frac {dv}{dx}$ which just calls for the power rule by itself.  I would count two applications of the chain rule and three of the power rule here.